# jython can't locate nltk_data

Tags: python, jython, nltk

I am trying to configure jython to work with nltk. In order to make jython aware of nltk i added the path of the `site_packages` of the python module installed in my machine (`"C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages"`) to the external libraries of the jython project i am implementing by adding that path to the build path under project properties of the project.
When I import `nltk.book` (`from nltk.book import *`), I get the following error:

```
LookupError: 
**********************************************************************
  Resource 'corpora/gutenberg' not found.  Please use the NLTK
  Downloader to obtain the resource:  >>> nltk.download()
  Searched in:
    - 'C:\\Users\\sodara/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/share/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/local/share/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/lib/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/local/lib/nltk_data'
```

I have tried downloading the nltk from within jython without much success.

The same portion of code runs perfectly in python without any error.

I am using python 2.7 and jython 2.5.3.

I found out that the python instance of nltk locates the nltk data in \AppData\Roaming\nltk_data

Answer (score 1):

Check the default download directory on your NLTK Downloader:

```
import nltk
nltk.download()
```

It's most likely `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\nltk_data` - I'd copy it to the directory that Jython is looking in.

Answer (score 0):

Like the error said, you need to download data (corpus and stuff) using `nltk.download()`

Add something like this in your code:

```
if not os.path.isdir(os.path.expanduser('~/nltk_data')):
    nltk.download(download_dir=os.path.expanduser('~/nltk_data')
```

You can also download only the packages you need:

```
nltk.download(package_name, download_dir=os.path.expanduser('~/nltk_data')
```

Comment: I tried using this path nltk.download(download_dir=os.path.expanduser('C:\\Users\\sodara/nltk_data'). Getting the error below. SyntaxError: mismatched input '\n' expecting RPAREN. Thought this was escape character problem tried \\nltk still getting same problem. +could you know why nltk can access data in python but not in jython?